# My app's [NSHTTPCookieStorage setCookie] destroys the browser's cookie?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm logging into an API via `[NSHTTPCookieStorage setCookie]`.
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html

If I log in while my browser is open, already logged in with the same user to the same site, both the app and the browser continue to work fine.

But if I `Quit` my browser, open it up again, and go back to the site, the cookie has been lost. User is not logged in.

What's going on here, and is there a way to force the app to use a different cookie than the browser?

Alternately, if we are "sharing" cookies between apps, is there any way I can use the already-logged-in user's cookie to log into my app without asking for a username/password?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here’s the code for create a new cookie, as you requested:
(Not tested in XCode)

```
// Dictionary of attributes for the new cookie
NSDictionary *newCookieDict = [NSMutableDictionary 
                               dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@".example.com", NSHTTPCookieDomain,
                                                            @"Test Cookie", NSHTTPCookieName,
                                                            @"/", NSHTTPCookiePath,
                                                            @"test1234567890", NSHTTPCookieValue,
                                                            @“2011-10-26 00:00:00 -0700", NSHTTPCookieExpires, nil];
// Create a new cookie
NSHTTPCookie *newCookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:newCookieDict];

// Add the new cookie
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:newCookie];
```

Special attention to the last element of the dictionary

Comment: Thanks, the issue being that I have a `NSHTTPURLResponse` that I'm using with `cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields:` to create a cookie. Worried that my "self-created" cookie in this answer will not preserve all the information from the header-field-created cookie.

Regardless, I don't think adding an expiration date is the correct answer for my base problem. Even the cookie created with the expiration date set to the future logs me out of the browser. I need a way to set a cookie just for my app, not touch other cookies. Similar to how Firefox/Chrome/Safari do not share cookies.

Comment: I asked a more specific question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922460/private-cookie-for-only-my-app-why-is-it-influencing-the-browsers-cookie

Answer (score 0):

Have you set an expiration date for the cookie? If you don't, NSHTTPCookie assumes to be session only ([link to docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookie_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSHTTPCookie))

Comment: Is that when you are declaring the NSHTTPCookie? How do you do that with `cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields:forURL:`?

Comment: When you use `cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields:forURL:` you obtain a `NSArray` of `NSHTTPCookie` objects. You can take each `NSHTTPCookie` using a loop and set an expiration date for each one.

Comment: I’ll post it in a new answer (no room here)