# Private cookie for only my app? Why is it influencing the browser's cookie?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

When I log into my app, my browser's cookie for the same site is lost. Why is this cookie being shared between apps? Logging-in in Chrome does not affect Safari's cookies, how can I emulate that behavior in my App Store app?

I am logging into a website's API and setting a cookie via: `[NSHTTPCookieStorage setCookie]`

Using [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html), I see two ways to get the cookie storage location:

`– initWithStorageLocation:` (Deprecated, Available in Mac OS X v10.6 through Mac OS X v10.6)

and

`+ sharedHTTPCookieStorage`

It seems like the first one is similar to what I want, using a unique storage loaction that is only usable by my app. But that method is deprecated in Lion? How then do you use a private my-app-only cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By not using the cookie-management of the OS but implementing your own. [IIRC Chrome on OSX uses an SQLite3 DB to store cookies and implements several parts of the browser/http/network communication itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528208/google-chrome-cookie-storage/4528256#4528256).