# Making WKWebView not share cookies with Safari in OS X

Tags: webkit, osx-yosemite, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

How do I make WKWebView not share cookies with Safari in OSX?

I have a very simple app that I made as an experiment that displays a WKWebView and as far as I can see, it's picking up cookies from Safari, because in my custom app, I'm logged in in the same websites as Safari.

I am currently creating the WKWebView instance like this:

```
override func loadView() {
    self.webView = WKWebView()
    self.view = self.webView!
}
```

in an NSViewController I created. I also tried this:

```
override func loadView() {
    var processPool = WKProcessPool()
    var config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    config.processPool = processPool
    self.webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100), configuration: config)
    self.view = self.webView!
}
```

but it made no difference to cookie storage. I don't have an issue creating my own cookie storage as long as it's not using hacks, as previous hacks for WebView did not work. I just need cookies to not be shared between my app and Safari.

Comment: This is an interesting issue... I thought i've been seeing something with cookie sharing between Safari and Firefox last few weeks that is bugging me. Found this... https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/index.html

Comment: "As a rule, cookies are shared among all applications and are kept in sync across process boundaries." does it mean there's no way around it?

Comment: Didn't know that... seems like a bad idea from a security standpoint. I saw some references to being able to get a private cookie jar in one of the stack answers. I'd look into that.

Comment: Seems like it ain't possible anymore, and if you want private storage you have to do it yourself!! See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922460/private-cookie-for-only-my-app-why-is-it-influencing-the-browsers-cookie

Comment: @CliffRibaudo What do you mean by do it yourself?

Comment: Implement your own cookie storage using coreData or some such.

Comment: @CliffRibaudo I'll be happy to implement my own cookie storage using whatever... this is actually part of what we want to do, but WKWebView, as far as I can see, doesn't let you do that. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Pablo It seems that you'd have to switch to UIWebView to have proper cookie behavior. Did you try that?

Comment: @gijswijs isn't UIWebView iOS only?

Comment: I found a open source project which addresses this problem. Author claims that it's not perfect but it can be a start point. https://github.com/cyyuen/ADCookieIsolatedWebView

Comment: The Captive Network Assistant which pops open when you have to sign in to use wifi seems to have its own cookie storage. (It would be security risk if it didn't since it opens automatically and an attacker could impersonate sites to see what cookies you have). It would be interesting to find out how it does it.