# Getting to know NSHTTPCookieStorage's internals

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to understand NSHTTPCookieStorage's internals to be able to swizzle some methods to have a separate storage from cookie storage from Safari, something that's impossible by any non-hacky way as far as I can tell:

- [Making WKWebView not share cookies with Safari in OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28741177/making-wkwebview-not-share-cookies-with-safari-in-os-x)
- https://devforums.apple.com/message/1115007

I located the header file here:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Headers/NSHTTPCookieStorage.h
```

which doesn't give me much information except that the implementation should probably be in

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
```

I look at the symbol names in that library but I only found these ones mentioning NSHTTPCookieStorage:

```
$ nm /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation | grep -i cookiestorage
000000000030cbb5 S $ld$add$os10.5$_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSHTTPCookieStorage
000000000030cbb6 S $ld$add$os10.5$_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSHTTPCookieStorage
000000000030cbb7 S $ld$add$os10.6$_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSHTTPCookieStorage
000000000030cbb8 S $ld$add$os10.6$_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSHTTPCookieStorage
000000000030cbb9 S $ld$add$os10.7$_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSHTTPCookieStorage
000000000030cbba S $ld$add$os10.7$_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSHTTPCookieStorage
000000000030cbbb S $ld$add$os10.8$_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSHTTPCookieStorage
000000000030cbbc S $ld$add$os10.8$_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSHTTPCookieStorage
000000000030cbbd S $ld$add$os10.9$_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSHTTPCookieStorage
000000000030cbbe S $ld$add$os10.9$_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSHTTPCookieStorage
                 I _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSHTTPCookieStorage (indirect for _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSHTTPCookieStorage)
                 U _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSHTTPCookieStorage
                 I _OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSHTTPCookieStorage (indirect for _OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSHTTPCookieStorage)
                 U _OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSHTTPCookieStorage
```

No methods at all. Doing a class dump of that library this is all the mentions of "Cookie" that I could find:

```
# class-dump /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation | grep -i cookie
@interface NSHTTPCookie (NSHTTPCookiePortCoding)
```

Things started to get a bit desperate, so I invoked strings!

```
$ strings /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation | grep -i cookie
setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:
NSHTTPCookiePortCoding
```

Using method swizzling, I wrapped a method around `NSHTTPCookieStorage`'s `sharedHTTPCookieStorage` and then I tried to enter it with the XCode debugger to see if I could at least get to the assembly of that method, but XCode would jump right over any calls to a method of that class even when I tell it to go in.

It looks like the class is not even there. Where is that class defined? How can I get to its internals?

Answer (score 0):

NSHTTPCookieStorage class is defined in CFNetwork.framework.